# Why scrollspy click not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, scrollspy

i had a scollspy page, my nav menu has a lot of items and nav items scroll to left or right when i scroll or click on nav links
in firefox everything is Ok. but in chrome :
when click on nav item, function not working, just on scrolling worked !
How can i fix this to work on chrome like firefox ?

jsfiddle demo :
https://jsfiddle.net/amirehsan/ec7bsndu/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sectionIds = $('a.fmenu_link');
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        sectionIds.each(function(){
            var container = $(this).attr('href');
            var containerOffset = $(container).offset().top;
            var containerHeight = $(container).outerHeight();
            var containerBottom = containerOffset + containerHeight;
            var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
            if(scrollPosition < containerBottom - 20 && scrollPosition >= containerOffset - 20){
                $(this).addClass('activef');
            } else{
                $(this).removeClass('activef');
            }
        });
        var myScrollPos = $('a.activef').offset().left + $('a.activef').outerWidth(true)/2 + $('.fmenu').scrollLeft() - $('.fmenu').width()/2;
        $('.fmenu').scrollLeft(myScrollPos);
    });
});
```

```css
html {
    font-size:15px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #202020;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.9;
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: left;
}
    section {
        background:#a00fff;
    }
    section:nth-child(odd) {
        background:#00ca20;
    }
    section:nth-child(3n+0) {
        background:#ffd227;
    }
    section:nth-child(4n+0) {
        background:#057eff;
    }
a {
    color:var(--black);
    text-decoration:none;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color:#000;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.fmenu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.fmenu_nav {
    display: flex;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
}
a.fmenu_link {
    padding:0 20px;
    border-radius:40px;
    margin:0 50px;
}
a.fmenu_link.activef {
    background:#3fbbe1;
    color: #fff;
}
section{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fmenu">
    <div class="fmenu_nav">
        <a href="#home" class="fmenu_link activef">Home</a>
        <a href="#about" class="fmenu_link">About</a>
        <a href="#work" class="fmenu_link">Work</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact2" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact3" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact4" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact5" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact6" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact7" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact8" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact9" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact10" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact11" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact12" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact13" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact14" class="fmenu_link">Contact</a>
        <a href="#contact15" class="fmenu_link">contact15</a>
    </div>
</div>
<section id="home"></section>
<section id="about"></section>
<section id="work"></section>
<section id="contact"></section>
<section id="contact2"></section>
<section id="contact3">contact3contact3contact3contact3contact3contact3contact3</section>
<section id="contact4"></section>
<section id="contact5"></section>
<section id="contact6"></section>
<section id="contact7"></section>
<section id="contact8"></section>
<section id="contact9"></section>
<section id="contact10"></section>
<section id="contact11"></section>
<section id="contact12"></section>
<section id="contact13"></section>
<section id="contact14"></section>
<section id="contact15"></section>
```